# About "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin Theorem 3.17(a).

Tags: proof-explanation, order-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am reading Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis".

There are the following definition and theorem and its proof in this book.

Definition 3.16:

> Let $\{ s_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ be the set of numbers $x$ (in the extended real number system) such that $s_{n_k} \rightarrow x$ for some subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$. This set $E$ contains all subsequential limits, plus possibly the numbers $+\infty$, $-\infty$.
>
> Put $$s^* = \sup E,$$ $$s_* = \inf E.$$

Theorem 3.17:

> Let $\{s_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ and $s^*$ have the same meaning as in Definition 3.16. Then $s^*$ has the following two properties:
>
> (a) $s^* \in E$.
>
> (b) If $x> s^*$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $s_n < x$.
>
> Moreover, $s^*$ is the only number with the properties (a) and (b).
>
> Of course, an analogous result is true for $s_*$.

Proof:

> (a)
>   if $s^* = +\infty$, then $E$ is not bounded above; hence $\{s_n\}$ is not bounded above, and there is a subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$ such that $s_{n_k} \to +\infty$.
>
> If $s^*$ is real, then $E$ is bounded above, and at least one subsequential limit exists, so that (a) follows from Theorems 3.7 and 2.28.
>
> ***If $s^* = -\infty$, then $E$ contains only one element***, namely $-\infty$, and there is no subsequential limit. Hence, for any real $M$, $s_n > M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$, so that $s_n \to -\infty$.
>
> This establishes (a) in all cases.

I cannot understand the following argument.
I am very confused.

Why did Rudin write "***, and there is no subsequential limit. Hence, for any real $M$, $s_n > M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$, so that $s_n \to -\infty$.***"?
I think this part is not necessary.

> If $s^* = -\infty$, then $E$ contains only one element, namely $-\infty$, and there is no subsequential limit. Hence, for any real $M$, $s_n > M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$, so that $s_n \to -\infty$.

By the way, my proof is here:

> If $s^* = -\infty$, then, $E = \emptyset$ or $E = \{-\infty\}$
>   And obviously $E$ is not $\emptyset$.
>   So $E = \{-\infty\}$.
>   So $s^* = \sup E = -\infty \in E$.

Comment: From my eyes, I feel like he is just "negating" what 3.17b is saying just to give more clarity.

Comment: $E$ cannot be empty.